# Cross Site Scripting Attack, troubles

Tags: javascript, html, dom, xss

I'm preparing for my final exam for a class and am attempting to rework homework problems. This is one of them that I got zero credit for the first time around.

The goal of this exercise was to create a URL that would point to the page with the HTML below, and instead of showing the collaboration policy intended, it would show my own, user created collaboration policy.

**Attempted the following without success...**

Escaped this

```
<script>document.getElementById('collab').firstChild = 'test';</script>
```

using this website
http://www.xs4all.nl/~jlpoutre/BoT/Javascript/Utils/endecode.html

and added it like this... 
www.cs.edu/vulnerable.html/?[insert escaped script here] and it didn't work. Any ideas on where I'm going wrong here?

**Here is the HTML code (vulnerable.html) for the page we are suppose to exploit.**

```
<html><head>
<script>
function loaded() {
  var parsed = document.location.href.match(/\?(.*)/);
  if (parsed && parsed[1])
    eval(unescape(parsed[1]));
}
</script>
<title>Example Page Title</title></head>
<body onload="loaded()" bgcolor="#ffffff">
<font face="Arial,Arial,Helvetica">

<table border=0 cellspacing=4 cellpadding=4>
<tr>
<td valign=top width="20%" bgcolor="#ffff66">
&nbsp;<p>
&nbsp;<p>
&nbsp;<p>
<a href="home.html">
Home</a> <p>

Course description <p>
<a href="notes.html">
Lecture notes</a> <p>
<a href="assign.html">
Assignments</a> <p>
<a href="ref.html">
Reference</a> <p>
&nbsp;<p>
&nbsp;<p>
&nbsp;<p>

</td>

<td valign=top width=800>

<h2 align=center>
Example course title
</h2>
<p>
<h3 align=center>Fall 2010</h3>
<p>


<h2>Syllabus</h2>

Syllabus here...

<h2>Collaboration policy</h2>

<P id="collab">
All assignments are strictly individual.  No collaboration
is permitted.



</td>
</tr>
</table>

</font>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as a general tip, use firebug to see where it messes up.  You can test the piece of JS that you send in by running it in the console in the page.

Comment: I wish I had been given homeworks like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove the script tags from vector. it is put to `eval` function which runs javascript, not html.

Also you want your vector to be:
`document.getElementById('collab').innerHTML = 'test';`

Comment: @user527627: you should upvote/accept an answer if you find it useful

Answer (score 0):

Hey, you should not modify nothing on that page (not even the eval). The page is vulnerable because it takes everithing thats added in the url and passes it tho eval function. Try to call your script with this `document.getElementById('collab').innerHTML="Very very wrong.Xss succeded"` after your testing link `www.cs.edu/vulnerable.html/?` (i mean call this `www.cs.edu/vulnerable.html/?document.getElementById('collab').innerHTML="Very very wrong.Xss succeded"` and instead `  Collaboration policy

All assignments are strictly individual. No collaboration is permitted.   `you will see`

  Collaboration policy

Very very wrong.Xss succeded
`
Now imagine you send the link above to someone and instead of injecting a harmelles text on that page you elaborate a script that steel his cookies for, lest say yahoo mail account (if it has one)....

Edit:
Nice homework by the way:D